# SBS 2011 Domain Limitations

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

Easy points for someone with magic Google hands: I know that with SBS, you can only have one domain, no trusts, no child domains, etc.  However, I cannot find that in "writing" anywhere for the life of me outside of the wikipedia article on small business server.  The [4] reference points to an SBS 2003 FAQ that's dead and I'd like to find an updated one for SBS 2011.

EDIT

Looking for official (Microsoft.com link to KB article, product page, white paper, etc.)/semi-official (SBS Blogs, etc.) references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this Microsoft wiki: [Small Business Server 2011 Standard - Build Document I. Overview of SBS 2011](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/small-business-server-2011-standard-build-document-i-overview-of-sbs-2011.aspx), please see the following section:

> **D.  PLANNING OF THE SETUP**
>
> ...
> SBS 2011 standard supports a maximum of 75 users or devices, must be the PDC, hold the FSMO roles, *and cannot support trust domains*.

Emphasis, mine.

At time of this answer, the quoted article revision was committed by Microsoft's own [Ed Price](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/ed%20price%20-%20msft/).

Comment: Well done, sir.

Answer (score 2):

[HERE](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/smallbusinessserver/thread/7572e3e6-0315-445f-b00b-ec77640535a1)'s one link that mentions the trust relationship bit, not found links for the other bits yet.

Comment: Well, if you can't have any trust, obviously you also can't have any other domain in the same forest...

Comment: Good point, well made :)

Comment: Yup, saw that, but need something official.